# what's the difference between *iter.first and iter->first?

Tags: c++11, stl, minmax

```
vector<int> a = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 };
pair<vector<int>, vector<int>::iterator> pair_of_itr;    //not working showing wrong directional error!
auto pair_of_itr = minmax_element(a.begin(), a.end());
cout << *pair_of_itr.first << " " << *pair_of_itr.second << endl;  // working with auto  but not with the PAIR of iterator.
//cout << pair_of_itr->first << " " << pair_of_itr->second << endl  // not working
return 0;
```

here i have explained via comments. plz do refer comments.

Comment: Have you looked at the type of [`minmax_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element)?

Answer (score 1):

`a->b` is the same as `(*a).b`. `*a.b` is the same as `*(a.b)`. So they differ in whether `a` is dereferenced, or `a.b` is dereferenced.

In your case, `auto pair_of_itr = std::minmax_element ...` creates a `std::pair` of iterators, and it is the iterator you want to dereference. So that would be `*pair_of_itr.first`. `*pair_of_itr` is ill-formed because a `std::pair` is not itself a pointer or iterator.

The problem with `pair<vector<int>, vector<int>::iterator> pair_of_itr;` is simply that the first element of the pair is a `std::vector`, not a `std::vector::iterator`. So in that case neither `pair_of_itr` nor `pair_of_itr.first` can be dereferenced. `*pair_of_itr.second` would compile, because the second element is an iterator.

It's usually a good idea to add redundant parentheses, particularly if you needed to ask whether they were necessary. Other people also might not remember that `*a.b` means `*(a.b)`, and the parentheses don't cost a lot.

Comment: pair<vector<int>, vector<int>::iterator> pair_of_itr;

This is not two iterators, but rather a vector and an iterator.

Comment: @marshall: yes, as i said: "the first element of the pair is a std::vector, not a std::vector::iterator." Was that not a clear enough statement?

Comment: No, it was clear;  I just missed it in the second para; sorry.